# How to run a python file importing another user defined module from command line

Tags: python-3.x

I have a project structure as below:

**Package:** unittestpackage

**Python Files:** test_class1.py, test_class2.py

**Note:** **test_class1.py** is importing the **test_class2.py**

I'm trying to run the test_class1.py from the command line using the below command but facing the below issue.

**Command used:** python test_class1.py

How can I run the test_class1.py which is importing the user defined module test_class2.py from command line.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `import unittestpackage.test_class2` but `import test_class2` or `import * from test_class2`, it should work.

Moreover, do you have a `__init__.py` file in your directory ?

Comment: Yes I have __init__.py file in my directory. But If I use just import test_class2 without the package name it throws an error.

Comment: try to use `chmod`